# Is CPUMINER's use of JSON files broken?

Tags: mining-pools, json-rpc, litecoin, cpuminer

This is regarding using cpuminer v2.3.2 to do Litecoin mining.

I recently upgraded my minerd from version 2.2.3 to 2.3.2  on both my win7(x64) and Ubuntu(x86) machines. Using the old version, minerd would run using  a "cfg.json" file by default if it was present or you could specify one with "-c myCfg.json". Now with the new version, it no longer "sees" or parses the config file even if it is explicitly told to.

To get 2.3.2 to run I had to specify all parameters directly on the command line.

The question is: has cpuminer changed its use of the old JSON format or is there a bug in that component?

On Win7, I now resort to a batch file for each mining site.

Thanks